# ProgressDialog showing for a fraction of a second, if at all

Tags: android

I am working on a calculator app for my first project with android. Some of the calculations take a while because of how many operands are put in the equation. I'm using mxparser api to evaluate the equation. A `progressDialog` is supposed to show during my `asyncTask`, but it only shows for a fraction of a second if at all.

I have tried other solutions on stackoverflow and nothing so far has worked. Any ideas as to why this is occurring?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editScreen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    editScreen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calculator_display);
    Button btnEq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_equals);
    btnEq.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String equation = editScreen.getText().toString();

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_equals:
            doCalculation(equation);
            break;

        default:
            Log.e("ERROR", "button was not implemented: " + v.getId());
    }
}

private void doCalculation(String equation) {
    Expression expression = new Expression(equation);
    boolean isCorrectSyntax = expression.checkSyntax();
    if (isCorrectSyntax) {
        new calcAsync(MainActivity.this, equation).execute(expression);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in expression, please check syntax", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private class calcAsync extends AsyncTask<Expression, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String equation;

    private String answer;

    public calcAsync(Context context, String equation) {

        this.equation = equation;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Expression... params) {
        Log.d("DEV", "starting calculation");
        Double result = params[0].calculate();
        String[] r = result.toString().split("\\.");

        if (result.equals(Double.NaN) || result.equals(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) || result.equals(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)) {
            answer = result.toString();
        } else if (r[1].length() == 1 && Integer.parseInt(r[1]) == 0) {
            answer = r[0];
        } else {
            answer = result.toString();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Calculating...");
        dialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();

        Log.d("DEV", "dialog shown");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (dialog != null) {
            Log.d("DEV", String.valueOf(dialog.isShowing()));
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("DEV", "Dialog dismissed");
        }
        editScreen.setText(answer);
        saveToHistory(equation, answer);
    }
}
```

}

Update 7/14/16:
It seems that the actual calculation itself doesn't take long at all. But from the time it takes after the equals button is pressed, until the result is displayed takes a while. 3 seconds for a long string of 1+1... (33 additions in my testing), longer if the string is longer than that.

Update 7/18/16:
I found out why my `progressDialog` wasn't showing. In the `doCalculation` method I am checking the syntax with `equation.checkSyntax()` before the `asyncTask`. This is where my delay was coming from, so the `asyncTask` wasn't doing the bulk of the work. after adding it in the `asyncTask`, I noticed that it takes considerably longer for the same test case as my previous update.

Comment: Why do you expect it to last longer than it does if the calculation is fast enough?

Comment: my roommate was playing with it and noticed that calculations that consisted of multiple operators tends to be slow. for example if the equation is adding 1, 30 times, it takes 5+ seconds to get the result. I think it has to do with how mxparser does the calculation. So I wanted to show a progressDialog to so that the user knows that a result is coming.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the delay occurs from the time the equals button is pressed, why not move the ProgressDialog to start there instead?

Comment: It has the same effect as putting it in the onPreExecute

Comment: what if you start it before the line `Expression expression = new Expression(equation);`

Comment: Then try even earlier in the code so you can see what is hanging it up. You already stated that the AsyncTask part hardly takes up any time, so it must be something else

Comment: The earliest it can be placed is in the switch statement in the onClick method. which doesn't make any difference